# Postgres SELECT DISTINCT, only highest values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using the following `pgsql` query to select `index_id` and making a distinct query on the level column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (level) index_id FROM indexes
```

Although its working, it is returning the first `index_id` for each level, i would like to get the highest `index_id` in each distinct level

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `order by` to get the max index_id

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (level) index_id 
FROM indexes 
order by level, index_id desc
```

Comment: When I do this, it doesn't necessarily give me the "last" row of the distinct set.  My rows seem almost random - maybe something wrong with my index?

Answer (score 6):

Try tou use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT ON

```
SELECT MAX(index_id)  FROM indexes GROUP BY level
```

Comment: What is faster: DISTINCT ON or MAX + GROUP BY?

Comment: I have heard DISTINCT ON is but dont' have source